# Rails update attribute in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, update-attributes

I want to update the `:position_status` in the model based on if `:position_date` which is equal `Date.today`, let say I have the `:position_date` which is `Mon, 26 Oct 2017` stored in the database, if the `Date.today` is on that particular date, then update the `:position_status`

I have tried to change the `position_date` to today date to see if it will update or not, but the `:position_date` was not updated.

```
attr_accessor :update_position_status

def update_position_status
 if Date.today == self.position_date
  self.update_attribute(:position_status => 'Filled')
 end
end
```

Comment: when calling this method you should get an error since `update_attribute` expects 2 arguments.

Comment: You should not use `attr_accessor` here. `attr_accessor` is for generating getter and setter methods for instance attributes - not for method accesibility.

Answer (score 2):

> update_attribute(name, value)
> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute

`update_attribute` updates a single attribute and skips validations. `update_attributes` takes a hash of attributes and performs validations.

So the corrected code would be:

```
def update_position_status!
  update_attribute(:position_status, 'Filled') if self.position_date.today?
end
```

The name should end with `!` since it mutates (changes) the object.

However updating the records one by one is not a particularly scalable solution. Instead you want to select the all the records by date and do a mass update:

```
# MySQL    
Thing.where("DATE(position_date)=CURDATE()")
     .update_all(position_status: 'Filled')

# Postgres
Thing.where("date_trunc('day', position_date) = current_date()")
     .update_all(position_status: 'Filled')
```

Comment: I have tried to change the code, however it doesn't update the `:position_status` automatically even I changed the date to today.

Comment: What do you mean automatically? You would need to use a scheduler like a cron tab and run it every day.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `update_attribute` requires two arguments.

The correct syntax is:

```
self.update_attribute(:position_status, 'Filled')
```